# Android service puts multiple instances of an activity in the history

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-intent

I'm making a music player.  When you press play, it loads a notification into the OnGoing section.  When you go anywhere else in the system, I want the music to keep playing.  All of this is fine.

The problem is that when I relaunch my activity from the Notification, it adds a task to the history stack each time, so if I hit back, I have to see the instance of Activity B from where I pressed play, and from every time I clicked on the notification to go back to Activity B.

I want the instance of Activity B that I launch from the notification (via the service) to be the only copy of that Activity in the history.  I've been playing around with various Intent flags and Activity attributes in the manifest, but I haven't found the proper combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

(called on your `Intent` you are using with your `PendingIntent` for your `Notification`)

Comment: You are my savior.  That's exactly what I needed.  A lot of your answers on other questions have helped me as well, so double thanks. =)